# How to express cheer myself up in another way

Tags: expressions

The circumstance is: I have been through some tough times, and now I am ready to cheer up and do some real job.

I think in some TV series or movies, I might hear something like:' I will put things up' to express that I am ready to go out of these hard times.

Is this the correct way to express it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could say *I pull myself together.*

> **pull yourself together** means to force yourself to stop behaving in a nervous, frightened, or uncontrolled way. (LDOCE)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this is what I've been looking for :)